# Unity - Collision detection within a collision detection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am shooting a ball at blocks, and there are 3 Mega Blocks that make the weapon stronger.  On my Mega Block 1, if a collision is detected from the Bullet Ball I shot, run code.  That works fine.  Now, if Mega Block 1 (tag=MegaBlock01) was hit, do one code, if Mega Block 2 was hit, etc.  I wanted to put this code block on each Mega Block so I don't have to write new code for each.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)  // This code is on my Mega Blocks
{
    if (other.CompareTag("BulletBall"))  // The Ball has hit me
    {
       StartMegaWeapon01();

        // What I want is:  
        // If my tag is MegaBlock01, run StartMegaWeapon01();
        // If my tag is MegaBlock02, run StartMegaWeapon02();

    }
}
```

I want a collision detection within a collision detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the collider of your bullet checked as IsTrigger since you invoke the `OnTriggerEnter` method. At least one of the 2 colliding objects also needs to have a rigidbody so that the physics engine can properly compute collisions.

Once you have that, getting the tag of the gameObject from `this` should be enough:

```
if (gameObject.tag == "MegaBlock01")
    StartMegaWeapon01();
```